# Optimize mysql view that merges multiple records into one record

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, view

I'm trying to optimize a view in MySql. The view takes 0-5 records from a table and turns them into 1 record. The view works, but is slowing down as the # of records in the property_log table increases.

For example, data that looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from property_log where event_id = 1144882;
+----------+--------------+------------------------------+
| event_id | log_key      | log_value                    |
+----------+--------------+------------------------------+
|  1144882 | userId       | 1000                         |
|  1144882 | licenseId    | 3                            |
|  1144882 | messageTypeId| 7                            |
|  1144882 | message      | Sample message               |
|  1144882 | op           | tracking                     |
+----------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

Gets turned into 1 record:

```
mysql> select * from view_logged_property where id = 1144882
+---------+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
| ID      | UserID | LicenseID | MessageTypeID | Message           |
+---------+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
| 1144882 | 1000   | 3         | 7             | Sample message    |
+---------+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Edit: Important Note - Not all 5 records will be present all the time. For example, the data could also look like this:

```
mysql> select * from property_log where event_id = 1144882;
+----------+--------------+------------------------------+
| event_id | log_key      | log_value                    |
+----------+--------------+------------------------------+
|  1144882 | userId       | 1000                         |
|  1144882 | messageTypeId| 7                            |
|  1144882 | message      | Sample message               |
|  1144882 | op           | tracking                     |
+----------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

The view I'm currently using to do this is the following:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_logged_property;
CREATE VIEW view_logged_property as (
  SELECT
    p.event_id as ID,
    (select log_value from property_log where log_key = "userId" and event_id = p.event_id) as UserID,
    (select log_value from property_log where log_key = "licenseId" and event_id = p.event_id) as LicenseID,
    (select log_value from property_log where log_key = "messageTypeId" and event_id = p.event_id) as MessageTypeID,
    (select log_value from property_log where log_key = "message" and event_id = p.event_id) as Message
  FROM
    logging_event p
  WHERE
    p.event_id in (select event_id from property_log where log_key = "op" and log_value = "tracking")
);
```

What's the best way to write this view so it'll perform well even as the # of records in the "property_log" table increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `join`s in this case.

Changed after comment `left join`s should solve problem.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_logged_property;
CREATE VIEW view_logged_property as (
    select 
        p1.event_id as ID, 
        p5.log_value as UserID, 
        p2.log_value as LicenseID, 
        p3.log_value as MessageTypeID, 
        p4.log_value as Message
    from property_log p1  
    left join property_log p5 on p1.event_id = p5.event_id and p5.log_key = 'userId'
    left join property_log p2 on p1.event_id = p2.event_id and p2.log_key = 'licenseId'
    left join property_log p3 on p1.event_id = p3.event_id and p3.log_key = 'messageTypeId'
    left join property_log p4 on p1.event_id = p4.event_id and p4.log_key = 'message'
    where p1.log_key = 'op' and p1.log_value = 'tracking'
);
```

Could you test it on your data?

Index on pair `event_id, log_key` might be required, sth like below:

```
 create index event_key_idx on property_log(event_id, log_key);
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93b65/2)

Comment: Hey! I tried this and it didn't give me back any data.... but that's because I didn't realize that not all records will be present all the time (sometimes there will be only 4 records, for example). I've added a clarification to the question!

Comment: @BradParks so instead of `join` use [`left join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), answer corrected.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a bunch... this was infinitely faster than my approach ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SELECT  Event_ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN log_key = 'userID' THEN log_value ELSE NULL END) userID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN log_key = 'licenseId ' THEN log_value ELSE NULL END) licenseId ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN log_key = 'messageTypeId' THEN log_value ELSE NULL END) messageTypeId,
        MAX(CASE WHEN log_key = 'message' THEN log_value ELSE NULL END) message,
        MAX(CASE WHEN log_key = 'op' THEN log_value ELSE NULL END) op
FROM     property_log
GROUP BY    Event_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/335dd/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*converted to VIEW*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b3f5/2)